# How to increase query speed in db4o?

Tags: database, optimization, db4o, large-data

[OutOfMemoryError caused when db4o databse has 15000+ objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142625/outofmemoryerror-caused-when-db4o-databse-has-15000-objects)

My question is in reference to my previous question (above). For the same PostedMessage model and same query.

With 100,000 PostedMessage objects, the query takes about 1243 ms to return first 20 PostedMessages.

Now, I have saved 1,000,000 PostedMessage objects in db4o. The same query took 342,132 ms. Which is non-linearly high.

How can I optimize the query speed?

FYR:
The timeSent and timeReceived are Indexed fields.
I am using SNAPSHOT query mode.
I am not using TA/TP.

Comment: You say you just want the 'first 20', is the information that you use to order the results indexed in the db?

Comment: Yes, it is indexed. I am not using the TA/TP. I am using SNAPSHOT query mode. And first 20, is because, I want to access the PostedMessages in paginated manner.

Comment: Can Gamlor comment on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Do you sort the result? Unfortunatly db4o doesn't use the index for sorting / orderBy. That means it will run a regular sort algorith, with O(n*log(n)). It won't scala liniearly.

Also db4o doesn't support a TOP operator. That means even without sorting it takes quite a bit of time to copy the ids to the results set, even when you never read the entities afterwards.

So, there's no real good solution for this, except trying to use some criteria which cut down the result size.

Some adventerous people might use a different [query evaluation](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/configuration/common/query_modes.htm), but personally don't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

@Gamlor No, I am not sorting at all. The code is as follows:

```
public static ObjectSet<PostedMessage> getMessagesBetweenDates(
        Calendar after,
        Calendar before,
        ObjectContainer db) {

    if (after == null || before == null || db == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Query q = db.query(); //db is pre-configured to use SNAPSHOT mode.
    q.constrain(PostedMessage.class);
    Constraint from = q.descend("timeRecieved").constrain(new Long(after.getTimeInMillis())).greater().equal();
    q.descend("timeRecieved").constrain(new Long(before.getTimeInMillis())).smaller().equal().and(from);
    ObjectSet<EmailMessage> results = q.execute();
    return results;
}
```

The arguments to this method are as follows:

after = 13-09-2011 10:55:55

before = 13-09-2011 10:56:10

And I expect only 10 PostedMessages to be returned between "after" and "before". (I am generating dummy PostedMessage with timeReceived incremented by 1 sec each.)