# Please explain the db4o PolePosition report

Tags: db4o

Can someone explain me how to read the PolePosition's benchmarking results in the link below?

http://polepos.sourceforge.net/results/PolePositionClientServer.pdf

So, let's take an example of ComplexConcurrency on page 2 in the above pdf.
On the graph, it says time=60000, updates=2, selects=20, threads=1, writes=3, objects=3. Does it mean that it took 60000 ms to run this complete test? The test included 2 update queries, 20 select queries. The application usd only 1 thread. Am I right? What does objects=3 means?

And on the right side of each bar graph there are numbers like 533, 430, 153, etc. What do these numbers signify?

I want to understand this report from db4o's perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know (could be totally wrong).

Then umbers shown like 533, 430 etc show how many iterations of operations ran within 60 seconds.

Then other number tell what is done withing a single iteration. It does like 2 update uperations, 20 select operations in one iterations. And 1 thread does those operations.

But for the exact info I would need to look at the code.

Comment: Considering the test results, it must be possible to optimize my query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319361/how-to-increase-query-speed-in-db4o

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319361/how-to-increase-query-speed-in-db4o